# Ember simple array to display in component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, selector

Simple array in an component, that it will be display in a selector tag. I'm not being able to make it to work. The firstSelector doesn't display anything.

In the component.js:

```
  sortPropertiesAsc: ['value:asc'],
  selectors: ['model.modelObjects', 'model.location'],

  firstSelector: function(){
     const firstGroupObjects = this.get('selectors')[0];
     return Ember.computed.sort(firstGroupObjects, 'sortPropertiesAsc');
  }.property(),
```

In the component.hbs

```
   <select onchange={{ action 'selectBrand' value="target.value" }}>
      <option value="" >Select company</option>
      {{#each firstSelector as |company|}}
         <option value={{company.id}} selected={{eq brand company.id}}>  {{company.value}}</option>
      {{/each}}
   </select>
```

if I write the firstSelector like this in the component.hbs, it will work:

```
 firstSelector: Ember.computed.sort('model.modelObjects', 'sortPropertiesAsc'),
```

How can I write it like the other way(as a function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure all that's at play in your setup, but one thing I noticed off the bat was if you want your [computed property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html) to fire based on changes to `selectors`, you'd want something like this.

```
  firstSelector: Ember.computed('selectors', function() {
     const firstGroupObjects = this.get('selectors.firstObject');
     return Ember.computed.sort(firstGroupObjects, 'sortPropertiesAsc');
  })
```

If `sortPropertiesAsc` changes values you'd want to add it in too

```
  firstSelector: Ember.computed('selectors', 'sortPropertiesAsc', function() {
     const firstGroupObjects = this.get('selectors.firstObject');
     return Ember.computed.sort(firstGroupObjects, 'sortPropertiesAsc');
  })
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!